# Calling a Future from another file in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, popup, call, future

I'm trying to get data to a different `.dart` file from `Future`.

For doing this, I created a class after `Future` code.

The code in pageone.dart:

```
 class Popups extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _PopupsState createState() => _PopupsState();
 }

 class _PopupsState extends State<Popups> {

  Future oyuncuSec() async {
     await showDialog(
       context: context,
...
...

  }
}

class UserService {
  oyuncuSec() {}
}
```

The code in pagetwo.dart, where I would like to call the same `Future` code:

```
import 'package:myappname/pageone.dart';

.
.

UserService userService = UserService();

.
.

    RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () => userService.oyuncuSec(), child: Text('Futbolcu Resmi'),),
```

But, when I run the page, and press on the RaisedButton (Futbolcu Resmi), it does not show up the pop-up. I'm stick on this for days. Please help me.

Comment: What is UserService and why are you trying to instantiate it?

Comment: I could not use the Popups class without an error. That is why I created UserService. If it does not work that way, I can delete it.

Comment: That's a good approach, thanks for the clarification. I'd suggest to make a folder called 'data' next to 'lib' and place the newly made class with the function in that file.

Comment: And use that function after instantiation in both the first and second pages.

Comment: I will write a detailed answer just a second...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you have created a separate class with the function definition inside it, that's the right way of doing it!

You must be missing something minimal in your code, make sure you define the class and the function as follows:

Let's say you are writing the class which has the function in a file called data.dart.

data.dart should look like this:

```
Class DataSource {
  Future oyuncuSec() async {
     await showDialog(
       context: context,
       ...
       ...
  }
}
```

Now let's say you want to use this function in a file called x.dart, this goes as follows:

in x.dart (which has a stateful widget), outside the build function:

```
var dataSource = new Datasource();

//an example function:
getData() async {
   await dataSource.oyuncuSec(); //use a .then() in the end if the function oyuncuSec returns something and you want to do something with the result... 
}
```

Edit: If you don't want oyuncuSec to return anything and just make a popup, there is no need to set its return type as Future. Just define it as `void oyuncuSec() {//code for popup}`

Comment: Thanks for your help Yudhishthir! I'm getting error for data.dart. I exactly did what you said. Most errors say "Method not found". Could you please help me solving this problem too?

Comment: Are you importing the data.dart file where you are calling the function?

Comment: I just solved the errors. Now, I only have an error saying "undefined name 'context'."

Comment: Sorry, you tried to help, but I still cannot show the popup.

Comment: You have to pass the context, define the oyuncuSec function as follows: Future oyuncuSec(BuildContext context) async {...}, and when calling it, pass context as a parameter as follows: await dataSource.oyuncuSec(context);